# google play - how often are the Developer Console statistics updated

Tags: android, google-play

As there are many androidians here I guess some experience can be shared. I can't find any concrete information how often the statistics on the google play Developer Console are updated (number of installs etc). My feeling is not more than once a day. Does anybody know?

Comment: I have kept a close eye on when the statistics update on my account recently, and I have found that they are updated every day at 1pm (UK time).

Comment: For me they are usually around 11pm GMT

Comment: their stat is bullcrap

Comment: Mine has only been updated once in the past week. The stat is about five days old. Is this normal? Does this only happen to me?

Comment: @Jonas That happened to me too once. Their stats are terrible and for me it is always a two day delay.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

They are *supposed* to be updated once every 24 hours.

However, Google Play is notoriously unreliable with statistics, and every now and then they stop updating for a few days. Even when updating, they tend to give out of date/incorrect data.

I'd suggest integrating [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/mobile.html) or [Flurry](http://flurry.com/) into your app(s) if you want good statistics.

Comment: Thanks Raghav - from your experience if you have, which of the two you would recommend, any significant differences between them?

Comment: I personally use Flurry, as I found out about GA much later, and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: thx for sharing your experience

Comment: I concur, developer console analytics has been giving me completely incorrect data. I added google analytics and it started reporting a lot more data (such as crashes etc).

Comment: Does any one knows what time exactly it is refreshed

Comment: Docs says "at 12:00 am PT" (midnight at Pacific Time Zone I presume) but for me 4 hours later there is no data for yesterday.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en

Comment: Try Twitter's Fabric, it is an amazing tool. It includes Crashlytics as @nizam.sp mentioned

Comment: In my experience, it updates around 0:00 - 23:59. Never accurate(by +1 GMT). In addition my statistics have a two day delay(meaning today I see the statistics for tuesday)

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin Around 2:30 PM IST for me (9:00 AM UTC)

Comment: As of this moment, my data is 5 days old. Disappointing.